# Woocommerce adding a new column in customers list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I would like to add a new column to Customers list.

[image]

This issue was evoked here [Add columns to WooCommerce Reports / Customer List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795050/add-columns-to-woocommerce-reports-customer-list), but there is no answer about the customer list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not easy task to do. This is using the built-in woocommerce admin plugin. There is still lack of good documentation.

Comment: I spent 2 hours researching this, and this documentation is the closest I found: https://developer.woocommerce.com/2020/02/20/extending-wc-admin-reports/